# Replacing a property key name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I feel like this will be one of those "oh jeez, how did I even ask this question" questions, but...

```
// So I create an object:
var o = {};

// I assign a string value to a variable:
var prop1 = "prop_key";

// And I use that variable that resolves to that string as the property name:
o[prop1] = "value1";

// => So far so good, the property key is the right value:
console.log(o); // => Object {prop_key: "value1"}

// Moving on, I am malicious and overwrite the `prop1` variable, replacing the original value to say, another string:
prop1 = "evil_string";

// And just to make sure it worked:
console.log(prop1); // => evil_value:

// AND YET, when I query the object...
console.log(o); // => Object {prop_key: "value1"}
```

Shouldn't it now output `Object{"evil_value": "val1"}` since `o[prop1]` no longer points to that original `prop_key` value?

Comment: prop1 refers to a variable not a reference to the object key

Comment: When you assign a new value to `prop1`, you lose the original reference. There will be an appropriate duplicate question somewhere round here

Comment: @Daemedeor Can you expand a bit in terms of what exactly happens? From what you say it sounds like, in step 3, does the value `"prop_key"` of var `prop1` merely get "copied over" as the key? (but it's never an actual reference to the object key)